# Is it possible to run Quickblox SDK in the background mode?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I want to prefetch new incoming messages when Push notification arrives to improve user experience

Apple says that in background mode (UIBackgroundModes: remote-notification) we need to use NSURLSession class to make network requests.

Is it possible to use QB SDK "as is" or I need to write my own wrapper for QB's REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to perform any QB requests in background?

All QB requests are asynchronous so it can be a case

Otherwise, QB SDK provides an access to the session token

```
[QBBaseModule sharedModule].token
```

so you can use it to perform requests in other way, e.g. using NSURLSession

QuickBlox does support **content-available** key in push messages.

The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a “silent” notification. When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get new data from your server or do background information processing. 
Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results from a silent notification, but they can find out about it the next time they open your app.

So it's up to developer how to react on content-available key, you can request some data from server or do nothing.

There is a special delegate **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:** which will be called in case of content-available key

Comment: Igor, thanks for your answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I didn't mean running QB queries in background thread, for example. I asked about background mode when app isn't showed on screen and generally suspended. Since iOS7 it is possible to wake up application, for example, to process incoming Push notification (make data/messages prefetch) to allow user immediately see new content when he or she returns to the app.

Comment: If you are about new key 'content-available' - yes, QB supports it

Comment: Yes, 'content-available' field in APNs payload is related to my question. Is QB supports 'content-available' "out of the box" or do I need to write own request to get messages in background? I didn't find this information in official docs.